# Which binary operator or function results in the least collisions?

Tags: math

Suppose we have two longs, x and y. What operator or function involving x and y would produce another long, z, which is least likely to be equal to the result of applying the same operator or function to different of x's and y's?

Ex: Addition would be a poor choice. 1+4=5, but 2+3 also equals 5.

EDIT: Let me explain why I'm asking this question. I'm creating a space rpg game. The game's environment (solarsystems) will be procedurally generated from two seeds. These seeds consist of the x and y coordinates of the system in the universe. So there is a good probability that the player might encounter the systems at (500,501) and (501,500) over the course of his adventures. I need a way to these the solar systems generated unique. But also, I want to make sure that as many coordinate pairs as possible will produce unique seeds.

EDIT 2: I tested two of the solutions given to me. Accipitridae's answer was far superior to Artelius's answer. Here's the code to test the solutions:

```
HashSet<Long> set = new HashSet<Long>();

 for(int x=0; x<1000; x++)
  for(int y=0; y<1000; y++)
   //I commented out one of the solutions at a time
   set.add((long)(((x&0x7FFFFFFF) << 33) | ((y&0x7FFFFFFF) << 2) |   ((x>>>62) & 2) | (y>>>63)));//Artelius
   set.add((long)(x - y * 7046029254386353131l));//Accipitridae

 System.out.println(set.size());
```

From the size of the HashSet, I could tell how many unique seeds were generated through each method. For these parameters, Artelius's solution generated 2048 unique longs, while Accipitridae's generated 1000000, meaning that there were no collisions at all.

Thank you all for you effort in trying to solve this problem. :)

Comment: Can't you use hashes? (md5, sha1)

Comment: Do we get to know more about `x` and `y`? For example, are they selected randomly from a range? Part of a distribution?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Lets say x and y can have values of any long, in Java. And the result should be a long also.

Btw, this isn't a hw problem. I need this for procedural generation for a space game.

Comment: It might help if you could say something about the distribution of your inputs. E.g., if your inputs are uniformly distributed over the longs then +, -, xor, ... are all fine. If there is a bias towards small inputs then other solutions might be preferable.

Comment: You implemented my function incorrectly. Probably changing (or casting) x and y to long ints will solve the problem. But I don't know enough Java to say for sure.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you need longs for the x and y co-ordinates? Just using *ints* gives you 18446744073709551616 possible grid locations, even a very addicted player would not be able to visit all of them. Using *longs* gives you 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 possible grid locations. If I were you I'd use ints, or restrict the universe size to something even smaller. Then this whole problem disappears!

Comment: Honestly, the large number of solar systems is purely for bragging rights.

Comment: Your comments say the values can be any java long.  Your tests say the values are less than 1000 and not negative.  Those usages do not at all agree with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like the answer and anlysis by Artelius. Especially the proposal to use

> f(x,y) = x + y*K

for some constant K is interesting and I'd like to just add a few more thoughts.
What I'm doing here is not new, but very closely related to the
[Fibonacci hashing](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus4/html/page214.html), which I think has been proposed by Knuth.

If we are using 64-bit integers then a collision f(x1, y1) = f(x2, y2) means

> 0 = (dx + dy * K) mod 2<sup>64</sup>,

where dx = x1 - x2 and dy = y1 - y2. This is the same as

> K = -dx*dy<sup>-1</sup> mod 2<sup>64</sup>,

where dy<sup>-1</sup> is the modular inverse modulo 2<sup>64</sup>. If we want to choose the K such that f(x1, y1) != f(x2, y2) whenever the differences dx and dy are both small then we have to choose K such that

> K = -dx*dy<sup>-1</sup> mod 2<sup>64</sup>,

has no solution such that both dx and dy are small. This can be achieved for example by choosing
K close to phi * 2<sup>64</sup>, where phi = (sqrt(5)-1)/2 is the golden ratio. The golden ratio has a very special continued fraction expansion, i.e. in a certain sense it is a number that is hard to approximate well with a fraction.

Hence, for 64-bit unsigned integers the following functions could be used

> f(x,y) = x + y * 11400714819323198485;

or equivalently when using signed 64-bit integers

> f(x,y) = x - y * 7046029254386353131;

Comment: So you think this is the best possible function for this problem? It is a bit hard to see the math, as I'm still in high school.

Comment: But, still, thanks a lot for the effort that you've put into this.

Comment: Best & easiest choice for K is some power of 2, (so that multiplication by K is equivilent to a simple and inexpensive left shift), and choosing the power such that after left-shifting, the result has NO bitwise overlap with x, (then the addition operation amounts to simple bitwise Or'ing)...   i.e., if K = 2^N, and x will always be less than 2^N, then x + Ky <=> x | (y << N) .

Comment: What the "best" solution is depends on how "best" is defined. Modern CPUs have very fast multiplicators, hence it is much less important whether a multiplication can be replaced by shift operations or not. Artelius has a definition for "best": i.e. f(x,y) should be uniformly distributed if the inputs x, and y are uniformly distributed. My proposal has the same property and additionally tries to minimize the number of collisions of inputs when the differences between the inputs are small. But if your requirements change, then of course the solution might as well.

Answer (score 7):

If `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` are two random pairs of inputs, then let `f1 = f(x1,y1)` and `f2 = f(x2,y2)`.

What you want to do is minimise

```
P( f(x1,y1) = f(x2,y2) )
 = P(f1 = f2)
 = sum for i in [LONG_MIN ... LONG_MAX]
        of P(f1 = i) * P(f2 = i)
 = sum for i in [LONG_MIN ... LONG_MAX]
        of P(f1 = i)^2
```

So you want to minimise the sum of the squares of the probabilities of each of your function's outputs. Since the *sum* of the probabilities must be 1, we know:

```
sum for i in [LONG_MIN ... LONG_MAX]
     of P(f1 = i)
  = 1
```

And we also know that for all i, `P(f1 = i)` is between 0 and 1 (inclusive). Intuitively, then, minimising `P(f1 = f2)` is a matter of making the probability distribution of `f1` as even as possible. (This can be proven mathematically but it's not really important to the question.) Ideally, `P(f1 = i)` and `P(f1 = j)` should be the same for all *long*s `i` and `j`.

Now let's look at some different possibilities for the nature of x and y.

First the general case, where x and y are uniformly distributed over the range of a *long*. (In other words, x is equally likely to be anything a long can be. So is y.) In this case, we can let `f(x, y) = x+y`, or `f(x,y) = x-y`, or `f(x,y) = x XOR y`, or even `f(x,y) = x` and (assuming normal integer overflow) we find that we have a uniformly distributed f, too, which means these functions are all "optimal".

But the `f(x,y) = x` example shows you that there's really not that much you can gain here.

However, in practice, your x and y will probably *not* be uniformly distributed. For instance, if x and y both drawn randomly from the range [0, 9999], then using `f(x,y) = x + y * 10000` will *always* produce different output for different input.

If, in each (x, y) pair, x and y are very likely to be near each other, for instance (1240,1249), (1,3), (-159720,-159721), then `f(x,y) = x` is actually quite a good candidate function.

If x and y are "probably not huge", then you should combine the 16 low bits of x with the 16 low bits of y, i.e. `f(x,y) = ((x&0xFFFF) << 16) | (y&0xFFFF)`, because the lower bits will be more evenly distributed than the upper bits.

This works very well if x and y are never negative. But if they are, the sign bit (that tells whether the number is positive or negative) might be more evenly distributed than some of the 16 low bits. So you may want to use it instead. E.g.

```
f(x,y) = ((x&0x7FFF) << 17) | ((y&0x7FFF) << 2) | ((x>>30) & 2) | (y>>31)
```

As the "probably not huge" case is quite common, I think this function would actually work quite well in general.

Comment: Nice. You might also consider to change the multiplier to an odd integer, e.g. f(x,y) = x + 10001*y. This has the advantage that for any y1 != y2 regardless of their size, we have y1*10001 != y2*10001. Hence f(x,y) never leads to a collision just by changing only x or only y.

Comment: I'm using Java for this program, where longs have 64 bits. I guess all of the constants would in that function will double huh?

Comment: Not quite, no. The final function would, I believe, be ((x&0x7FFFFFFF) << 33) | ((y&0x7FFFFFFF) << 2) | ((x>>>62) & 2) | (y>>>63). Not sure if that's perfect Java, but I know you would have to use the >>> operator.

Comment: @Artelius: I think there is a typo in the formula above. First the bits 31..62 of x do not influence the result. Also at least some of the OR operators should probably be replaced by XORs or addition, since right now there is a bias towards resutls with many bits set to 1.

Comment: Bits 31..62 of x and y aren't *meant* to influence the result. I'm throwing them away, because I'm assuming that they're almost certainly zero. And if they're nonzero, the lower bits could be anything.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you limit the set of possible output values to the SAME set of values as the operands you are using as operands, then you cannot do any better than addition. Addition, actually, is probably the best possible choice, because it is simplest.  (See analysis below)

There are 2^64 possible longs, so there are 2 ^ 127 possible unordered pairs of longs, and only 2^64 possible longs for an answer, so the best possible distribution ratio is to have 2^ 63 different pairs that give the same answer, which addition, (with rollover) in fact, will do

EDIT: based on comments below.

however many (say it's N bits) a long is, there are 2^N different longs, so there are 2^N x 2^N ordered pairs of longs, but for the purposes of this analysis, using two longs x, and y is exactly the same as using y and x (the binary op is assumed to be communitative), so there are 2^ (2N-1) unordered pairs of longs.

so using unordered pairs (half as many) there are 2^N x (2^N-1) or 2^ (2N-1) pairs of longs without duplicates. (If N = 64, that's 2^127)   So the maximum "distribution" of assignment of answers (from the smaller set of 2^64 longs) to the unordered pairs of operands (the larger set of 2^ 127 pairs) is if they are equally distributed.  Thats what addition would do, because for each of possible long in the set of all longs, the sum of it with every other long (with rollover) will be a set of ... every long.

the only thing using ordered pairs does is allow you to use a non-communtative operand as well, but then you have to deal with all the cases where the answer is not in the set you are using for operands (like 5/4 )but even if you just assume rounding, the only impact on the analysis is that by using ordered pairs you get 2^2N different pairs of operands, instead of 2^(2N-1).

What you might do is limit the set of integers to be used as the operands to less than the square root of the number of possible longs (so if you are using 64 bit longs, limit your input values to 32 bit longs) Then, if you want absolutely no overlap or duplication (No case where A op B = same value as any other C op D), you can use the multiplication operator but for each value X in the smaller set of potential operands, choose the Xth prime number as the multiplicative operand. that way, no matter what two values A and B you randomly pick (from 1 to Max)  the operantion would be multiplication of two different primes.  This means the set of possible operands has to be smaller than the set of prime numbers equal to or less than the maximum possible value you are using for operand (if it's 64 bit unsigned longs, that 2^64)

2nd EDIT: based on yr specific problem, the set of possible operands is limited to the dimensions of a computer screen, considerably less than the number of longs, (no matter what platform you are on)  So a very easy and obvious way to guarantee that every pair of possible screen cooridinates will generate a distinct and different seed key is to simply left shift the value of one coordinate sufficiently to guarantee no bitwise overlap with the other coordinate, and then bitwise Or the result with the other coordinate.

So if your screen is say, 3000x3000, then long lngVal = (x<<12 | y) would do it with minimal computational overhead as well.

Comment: A long is 32 bits, in standard C at least.

Comment: A long is *not* 32 bits in standard C, unless you're using some new definition of the word "standard" of which I was previously unaware.

Comment: If I had time, I'd check the standard. I happen to be in a hurry. If you're going to flame me, you could at least explain what a long is actually defined as rather than just saying I'm wrong.

Comment: @Atelius: From 3.9.1 Fundamental Types: " There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”. In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list." The standard doesn't specify their actual sizes, just the relationships. There *are* specific types with set sizes (char32_t et al) but long is not one of them.

Comment: And it wasn't meant to be a flame. I just don't like to see people suffering under misapprehensions. I, for one, pronounced paradigm "pa ra dij m" for quite a while before someone set me straight that it was "pa ra dime" - I wonder how many people during that time wondered WTF I was talking about :-)

Comment: The "previously unaware" comment is a tribute to Douglas Adams (of HHGTTG fame) by the way.

Comment: Hah!  for the first 5 years that I knew the word (from building acft models), I thought fuselage was few-SELL-a-gee" !

Comment: Just to provide some concrete examples, a long is *not* 32 bits in OS X or most (all?) linuxes when running on x86_64. In fact, windows is the only OS I know of on which a long is 32 bits for 64-bit code.

Comment: Can you guys explain to me why "the best possible distribution ratio is to have 2^ 63 different pairs that give the same answer"?

Comment: Thanks Pax, I stand corrected. Nonetheless, on a 32-bit machine longs are usually 32 bits.

Comment: @Artelius Unless you are programming in Java, where long is 64 bits. Anyway, for the purpose this question it doesn't matter.

Comment: -1 for getting the probabilities wrong (hint: use ordered pairs).

Comment: Right, Java! Today is not my day.

Comment: @Penchant, see additional analysis in my answer.

Comment: @starblue, why use ordered pairs ? for any communitative operation, duplicate pairs give (x,y  and y,x) will give the same answer.

Comment: I never said that each solar system took only one pixel, so your assumption that they will not be much higher is wrong. My intention is that there be hundreds of millions of them. Sorry, if my problem is unclear.

Comment: @Penchant,  no matter how many 'pixels' each solar system takes, the key to the answer to yr question lies in the ratio between that number and the number of different longs that exist.  If the 'coordinates' of your solar system will be nbetween 1 and 2^32 (and that's a very large number, then you can use the approach I mentioned (generating a 64 bit long whose low 32 bits are from x-ccord, and high 32 bits are from the y-coord) and still not ever have a duplicate.

Comment: @Charles Bretana Yes, but to get the correct probability you have to count the unordered pairs.

Comment: @starblue, re: probabilities. To be honest, I'm still not getting  yr point. What do probailities have to do with this? The only prob involved is prob of encountering a specific set of coordinates, (x,y) - which a) is not specified, so it can be asssumed to be the same as for any other set, and b) has nothing to do with what the outcome of calculating the result of x op y.  And, as I said, if the chosen op is commutative, then x op y = y op x, so for the purposes of this analysis, in that case, unordered pairs is a more appropriate choice.